# AWS Cognito unauthenticated users ids consistency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm new to AWS, and i'm using Cognito **Identity Pools** to allow **unverified (unauthenticated)** users access to my AWS resources. I want to create users table using DynamoDb and my question is:

Is unauthenticated users ids in Cognito are consistent among devices? Will the id be constant for each device or change due to any reasons?
Can I use Cognito uid to identify a specific user even if he deletes the app for example, and comes back after few months?

THANKS.